# Can I force a workstation to use a specific domain controller?

Tags: domain, domain-controller, windows

I'm on a domain that I can't control the domain controllers on, but I can control my systems. All the domain controllers are part of one site, and that cannot change.

However, one of the domain controllers is not working correctly and the admins in charge of it are taking forever to resolve the issue. There are 6 total domain controllers... for some reason my workstations/servers are still attempting to use the bad one to authenticate my users.

Is there a way to force a workstation to use specific domain controllers? or, better yet, force it to NOT use the bad one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never done it, but supposedly you could use the #PRE tag in the lmhosts file on each workstation to set the preferred domain controller back in NT 4.0 days. Not sure if it still works, but it's worth a try. You can read about it at Microsoft Technet [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751197.aspx) under the "Specifying Domain Controllers" section. Make sure to reboot after lmhost changes.

Take a look at that entire document. That has more about lmhosts files in it than I ever wanted to know.

Comment: FWIW - this didn't work for me, & I triple-checked my Lmhosts config - might have to do with my Domain config though (Functional level is 2008 R2)

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem on WinXP machines before. Not finding a more elegant solution and being in a hurry I searched the registry for the name of the defective domain controller and replaced it with the name of the good one, followed by a reboot. I'd be more specific about the keys involved if I could but that was years ago.

Comment: Living on the edge, man. I approach the registry like it was a starved panther with astigmatism that makes me look like a tender chuck roast. Do you juggle flaming chainsaws in your spare time? =)

Comment: The registry is just another flat file database (or more accurately, a collection of them). If you happen to screw it up just restore from the backup you made before starting the edits.

Comment: I do see the offending domain controller listed several times in my server's registry... ugh. I'll try to switch them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled finding a solution to this problem for years. Neither registry changes or LMHOSTS modifications have been reliable - finally I think I've found a solution that works, however, it is risky at best so use at your discretion.

Simply manipulating the HOSTS file (%WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts) to forcibly point all ***other*** domain controllers to the domain controller of choice, ***when the NIC is initializing*** (presumably as TCP/IP is loaded up) will point your client machine at a different DC.

For example: If my PC keeps pointing at DC1-SITE1 (you can check by running `nltest /dsgetdc:DOMAIN` ), and I want to point at DC16-SITE3, I first find out all the domain controllers in my Site/Domain by running:

```
nltest /dclist:DOMAIN
```

Then, I simply point all the ***other*** domain controllers at the one I want in the HOSTS file. If my DC16-SITE3 IP is 10.1.1.1, then this would look like this:

```
10.1.1.1 DC1-SITE1
10.1.1.1 DC1-SITE2
10.1.1.1 DC2-SITE2
10.1.1.1 DC3-SITE10
...
```

and so forth.

Then, go into your network connections (Start -> Run -> ncpa.cpl), Right-click & "Disable" the NIC, then re-enable it. Re-run `nltest /dsgetdc:DOMAIN` and voila. If you get a different domain controller connection, check to make sure it was repointed in HOSTS.

Since this would probably cause side-effects, I've only used to temporarily test if problematic behavior is consistent across different domain controllers - then I revert the HOSTS file back to normal as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a totally dead thread but....couldn't you just run powershell to reset the computer password and point it to a new DC?

Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server "NewDomainControllerNameHERE"